# elfinder module throws jquery error in drupal 7

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7, elfinder

I have installed elfinder module in drupal 7 but it throws jQuery error when we loading elfinder page but file handling functionalities fine. Also icons in elfinder not aligned properly.

[Click here for elfinder icons issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJ7CT.png).

> TypeError: $(...).once is not a function
>   $('.colorbox', context)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define $

```
   (function($){
       $(document).ready(function(){
          var context = $('body'); // or what you want
          $('.colorbox', context).dowhatyouwant();
       });
    })(jQuery.noConflict());
```

Comment: I tried with below code, but still doesn't work.
Also why icons are misaligned? https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJ7CT.png

 (function($){
       $(document).ready(function(){
             $('.colorbox', context)
                   .once('init-colorbox')
                  .colorbox(settings.colorbox);
       });
    })(jQuery.noConflict());

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i couldn't fix that. Can you give me updated colorbox.js which is located in colorbox module?

Comment: verify path of your icons and physical existance of your icons

Comment: ok. I just fixed that icons mis-aligned issue with alter of elfinder-mi.css. Can you give me updated colorbox.js which is located in colorbox module?